# PHP curl not posting to correct fields

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl to retrieve some data on a post request, I'm having a little trouble with the fields as it doesn't seem to be correctly posting to the correct fields. The form consists of just a text area and a submit button.

```
<form action="other.php" name="form1" id="formID" method="post">
<textarea rows="1" cols="1" id="txtareaID" name="txtAreaName"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="btnID" name="btnName" value="btnValue" title="btnTitle">
```

This is the fields variable:

```
$this->fields = "txtAreaName=". $this->num . "&btnName=btnID";
```

I am not entirely sure how to identify the submit button in this case..

and here is the curl array:

```
array(
  CURLOPT_URL   =>  $this->address,
  CURLOPT_POST =>   true,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $this->fields
);
```

Comment: Have you tried with `btnName=btnValue` instead of `btnName=btnID`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not posting to the correct fields"? What fields is it posting to instead of the fields you want?

Comment: Make sure you use `urlencode()` if the field value can contain any special characters.

Comment: yea i am using urlencode(). I mean that curl is redirecting me to the page, but the page it's showing isn't what it would like had the data been posted so my only guess is that the fields are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit button should be:

```
"&btnName=btnValue"
```

The value to the right of the `=` should be whatever is in the `value=` attribute of the button.

Comment: Thanks, still not working for me. The ID's and such I gave are just an example, if I give you the site could you have a look for me? Everything looks ok to me, I'm stuck as to what might be the problem